# Magento 2 migration process with site improvements

Tags: magento2

We are currently in the process of migrating to Magento 2.1.x from 1.9.0.1. In our project, we are also improving our catalog, design, UX, and a few other components with this opportunity. We are at a place where we have successfully used the data migration tool to migrate the data to our dev environment and have modified the catalog to improve the attribute sets, design, and UX.

I have tried using the data migration tool's "delta" option but unfortunately, it's breaking due to different attributes. This makes sense with our improved catalog.

I need to choose a direction to put my effort toward and I think there may be other folks out there also migrating to Magento 2 and improving their Magento site during the process. My goal here is to gather ideas and solutions for our own project but also share those solutions to help other others and future migrations.

*Production (1.9.0.1)*

- Still, live and collecting orders/customers

*Development (2.1.4)*

- Used the data migration tool to import the first set of data from
  1.9.0.1.
- Changed the attribute sets, products, and categories to improve our Magento installation.
- Added new modules for shipping and payment

**OPTION A:** Try to get the delta command working in the data migration tool

- The idea is to modify the config and mappings (maybe the code) in the data migration tool to get the "delta" migration to work with the new modified catalog.

**OPTION B:** Migrate customers and orders from 1.9.0.1 production to 2.1.4

- The idea is to modify the config and mappings (maybe the code) in the data migration tool to only pull ONLY the customer entities and order entities (with the associated attributes).

**OPTION C:** Start from scratch, run the data migration tool, import the catalog

- The idea here is to use a base Magento 2 install, run the data migration tool with production data, then export the catalog from our dev site and import into the new production site.

If you have performed an M1->M2 migration and have some thoughts about which option you have used (or would use), it would be helpful to talk this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Delta migration reference: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

Best,
Gary

Comment: Gary, in my oppinion this "question" is not a good fit for this portal (stackoverflow). There is https://magento.stackexchange.com, which is probably better suited (and I think its easy to move this 'question' over). HOWEVER, your Post and your own answer is really well thought out and written, thanks for the effort you put in it. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research and testing, we decided to go with OPTION B "Migrate customers and orders from 1.9.0.1 production to 2.1.4". One thing we realized was, we didn't need any of the customers or orders in our development environment as they were imported from the initial migration and test orders.

Please note, the following information is NOT all inclusive as it would take several pages of information to share that level of detail. These are the broad steps we followed over several days of test runs and several dozens of hours of tweaking and testing.

Here is the process we followed:

---

**Step 1:** Created a new environment where we took the development code and data and migrated the production data into. We called this environment "stage".

**Step 2:** Copied the development environment into stage.

**Step 3:** Wrote a script to truncate the stage tables involved with customers and orders

**Step 4:** In the stage environment, copied the 1.9.0.1 folder in the migration tool to 1.9.0.1-phase2.

**Step 5:** Modified the config xml and commented out the steps OTHER THAN "Customer Attributes Step", "Map Step", "Log Step", and "OrderGrids Step".

**Step 6:** Modified the map xml and ignored any tables we didn't need to migrate outside of the customer and order tables like "design_*", "eav_*", "catalog*", "cms_*", and about 16 more ignore statements.

**Step 7:** Put production into maintenance mode, got a fresh copy of the production database and put it on our non-production server (we created a separate database from dev and stage called m1).

**Step 8:** Ran the migrate:data command with the "-r" flag and pointed to our phase2 config directory mentioned in step 4.

**Step 9:** We had to modify the auto increment of the sequence tables to match production.

**Step 10:** Tested on stage to confirm it's exactly what we wanted with the catalog, configuration from dev and the customers and orders from production.

**Step 11:** Migrated stage to production

---

If anybody else is Migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and modifies the site's catalog as part of the project, I hope this gives you a direction to follow. If anybody has a better method than we followed, please share to help future migration teams.

Best of luck!
Gary

Comment: If you could - by accident - throw in the script from step 3 that would be sweet :).